# Auto-run is stuck

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Whenever I get in combat, the character I'm controlling will continually run forward. This only happens in combat; as soon as all the swords get put away, he'll stop moving.

I suspect this is somehow related to the "Toggle auto-run" command in the key bindings. To try and make the problem go away, I moved "Toggle auto-run" from G to Backspace. That made no difference. I know I'm not pressing that button, but my character acts like Auto-Run is turned on. I try pressing the button to turn it off and it doesn't work. How can I make my character stand still?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem went away on its own a few days later.